# DELPHI, WebService (SOAP) can't make it retrieve the data

Tags: xml, delphi, soap

I have downloaded a schema for that webservice and then used the "RestDebugger" to create necessary pascal-files. The response from the webservice contains a schema and a "diffgram" part. The diffgram and schema is contained in a section called  but the original code, created by the "RestDebugger" did not contain the "diffgram" section. I had to add that to the pascal-file manually.

Ok, so far so good, but when I tried to retrieve the data from this part I've failed. I've used the XML Mapper to create a transformation file to be used with the component TXMLTransform. I have connected this component to TDataset and a TDBGrid but I only get the column-captions but no data.

the code for that looks like:

```
 XMLTransform1.SourceXMLFile := 'xml1.xml';
 ClientDataSet1.XMLData := XMLTransform1.Data;
 ClientDataSet1.Active := true;
```

The transform file is setup in the components property: TransformationFile: "Test.xtr"

It doesn't care what the datafile contains as long as it is valid xml. The result is a grid that shows all columns with correct captions  but no data.

I've read a lot of documentation about this but I'm not able to find any doc that helps me with my problem. I'm not sure what doc I should include here, there is a lot of text, but I'm pretty sure that it must be something very fundamental that I'm missing so a simple but complete instruction/sample would be enough I think.
Otherwise I think I have to create my own parsing function that at least works on this particular project. But that feels heavy.

The response in short:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Body>
      <GetDataBySecureResponse xmlns="https://xxxxx.getdata/">
         <GetDataBySecureResult>
            <SearchNumber>674564784</SearchNumber>
            <TransactionId>1199</TransactionId>
            <Block_Name>BSDA_C_BASIC</Block_Name>
            <Parameters>
               <xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
               <diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
                  <NewDataSet xmlns="">
                     <GETDATA_RESPONSE diffgr:id="GETDATA_RESPONSE1" msdata:rowOrder="0" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted">
                        <ORGNR>674564784</ORGNR>
                        <NAME>NICE NAME</NAME>
                  </NewDataSet>
               </diffgr:diffgram>
            </Parameters>
         </GetDataBySecureResult>
      </GetDataBySecureResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

In this simple example I'll get the grid populated with two columns, "ORGNR" and "NAME" but no rows.

Comment: The data is in the response so you are retrieving it fine. Your difficulty is in extracting the data.

Comment: Yes, that correct. I have difficulties in extracting the data and don't know how to fix it. Tried several solutions but still failing.

Comment: are you sure your web service is working? try resulting small results first

Comment: Yes, it's working. It's not my webservice it's a commercial one so I'm absolutely sure it's working. And also, I receive the complete soap response. I just can't make it update the datasets with data. I've made my own parser now so I can extract every field I need from the service but  I hoped that I could get the data into the datasets automatically.

Comment: Maybe not the answer you want to hear but the xml origins from a microsoft webservice. It will be far easier to consume this webservice via vb.net or C#... (dataset)